# LayoutのGUIエディタにのみ表示されるダミーテキスト機能はあるか

Tags: android

LayoutのGUIエディタを用いて、Layoutを作成しています。

例えば、TextViewの中身が動的に変わる場合、私は、今は空文字列に設定しています。
動的に変わる処理が走るまではユーザーには空文字列として見せたいからです。

しかし、GUIエディタ上では、空文字列だと何かと作りにくいです。

そこで、GUIエディタ上でのみ表示されるダミーテキスト(テキストに限らないですが)を指定する方法などがあれば知りたいです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tools 名前空間というのがありまして。

[Designtime Layout Attributes - Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes)

レイアウト XML のルート要素に xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" を追加して、あとは個々の要素で android の代わりに tools を接頭辞に用いた属性を記入していきます。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Dummy Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```